# Object Orientated CSS - Defining Colours

Tags: html, css

I am trying to convert to object orientated CSS. I am looking to define the colours:

```
/* COLOURS */
.gray5: { color: #4C4C4C; }
.gray4: { color: #333333; }
.gray3: { color: #999999; }
.gray2: { color: #808080; }
.gray1: { color: #F5F5F5; }
.white: { color: #FFFFFF; }
```

The trouble is, I want to define my colours like this but I can only define text colour like this. Is it not possible to do it so I can use this "colour" definition on either text or divs? I would rather not have to do it like this....:

```
/* DIV COLOURS */
.gray5: { background-color: #4C4C4C; }
.gray4: { background-color: #333333; }
.gray3: { background-color: #999999; }
.gray2: { background-color: #808080; }
.gray1: { background-color: #F5F5F5; }
.white: { background-color: #FFFFFF; }

/* TEXT COLOURS */
.tgray5: { color: #4C4C4C; }
.tgray4: { color: #333333; }
.tgray3: { color: #999999; }
.tgray2: { color: #808080; }
.tgray1: { color: #F5F5F5; }
.twhite: { color: #FFFFFF; }
```

Thank you for any input!

Comment: I would suggest you look into SASS or LESS.

Comment: @chovy: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/

Comment: I edited my css to be valid. Looks like I would need SASS or LESS to achieve this. :(

Comment: It's still not valid, and this question shouldn't be tagged OOP, OOCSS !== OOP.

Comment: @JamesWillson it's probably for the best, OOCSS is a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.  CSS Preprocessors are actually able to deliver on the promise of truly reusable CSS.

Comment: Why is it not valid CSS still? :'(

Comment: Not valid ".gray5: { color: #4C4C4C; } " Valid ".gray5 { color: #4C4C4C; } "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a CSS variables spec that is going through the early specification phases at the moment which will help you with this sort of thing (in the same way as SASS or LESS).

However it will a while before any browsers support it, and even longer before enough browsers support it to be usable in the real world. Until then, SASS and LESS are your best bets.

Reference:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables/
- http://www.xanthir.com/blog/b4KT0